# How do I change button text from "Choose an option" in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How would I go about changing this PHP code to to change Choose an option based on the id of the select element in the Woocommerce plugin for WordPress? I believe I have found the correct PHP file in wc-template-function.php but my lack of PHP skills is holding me back. Here is what I have so far:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options' ) ) {

    /**
     * Output a list of variation attributes for use in the cart forms.
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @since 2.4.0
     */
    function wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( $args = array() ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'options'          => false,
            'attribute'        => false,
            'product'          => false,
            'selected'         => false,
            'name'             => '',
            'id'               => '',
            'class'            => '',
            'show_option_none' => __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ),
            'show_option_color' => __( 'Choose a color', 'woocommerce' ),
            'show_option_size' => __( 'Choose a size', 'woocommerce' )
        ) );

        $options   = $args['options'];
        $product   = $args['product'];
        $attribute = $args['attribute'];
        $name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $class     = $args['class'];

        if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
            $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
            $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
        }

        echo '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '">';

        if ( $args['show_option_none'] ) {
            echo '<option value="">' . esc_html( $args['show_option_none'] ) . '</option>';
        }
        if ( $args['$id_colors'] ) {
            echo '<option value="">' . esc_html( $args['show_option_color'] ) . '</option>';
        }
        if ( $args['$id_sizes'] ) {
            echo '<option value="">' . esc_html( $args['show_option_size'] ) . '</option>';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
            if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
                // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
                $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                    // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.
                    $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        }

        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

You can see where I tried to add show_option_color and show_option_size in to the array and then add if statements for them, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure how to reference the id of the select element and write the if statement based on if its is the correct select element.

Here is the HTML I'm trying to target.

```
<select id="sizes" class="" name="attribute_sizes" data-attribute_name="attribute_sizes">Want this to say Choose a size</select>

<select id="colors" class="" name="attribute_sizes" data-attribute_name="attribute_sizes">Want this to say Choose a color</select>
```

variable.php code lines 27 - 38:

```
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify this part?

'Choose an option based on the id of the in the '

Did you mean based on the id of the product?

Comment: Sure. Each product either has no option to select from, a select a size option, a select a color option, or both options. However instead of saying select a size or select a color they all just say "Choose an option". I just want each one to say Select a color or Select a size based on what you are actually selecting. The select a color buttons have an id of #colors and the select a size buttons have an id of #sizes, but the display text for both says "Choose an option. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Look for an answer shortly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for a custom filter! I am first going to describe a method that is not the quickest way, but it is probably the cleanest and easiest to understand for anyone else who might have to read your code. I will also describe a 'dirtier' way that should do the job if you are in a time crunch.

**Quick Way:**

The place to find where this is displayed is in the file:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php
```

Around line 27, depending on your version of WooCommerce, you will see something like this line:

```
<option value=""><?php echo __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ) ?>&hellip;</option>
```

The __() function is running the first parameter through WordPress's translation system using the 'woocommerce' text domain. It is best to preserve the possibility for translation, so we will want to change this text before we send it through the translation function.

This line of code happens during a loop that outputs all of the product variation attributes. This allows us to easily see which attribute is being output by looking at the **$name** variable.

We will need to make a function that takes in the $name variable and outputs a string based on it. It would look something like this:

```
function get_text_for_select_based_on_attribute($attribute) {

// Find the name of the attribute for the slug we passed in to the function
$attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($attribute);

// Create a string for our select
$select_text = 'Select a ' . $attribute_name;

// Send the $select_text variable back to our calling function
return $select_text;
}
```

Now, before the code on line 27 of variable.php, we can put something like this:

```
<?php 

  $select_text = get_text_for_select_based_on_attribute($name);

?>
```

Then, simply swap out 'Choose an option' with your $select_text variable:

```
<option value=""><?php echo __( $select_text, 'woocommerce' ) ?>&hellip;</option>
```

Don't forget to do this all in a template override or your customization will be lost on the next update!

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

**Cleaner Way:**

A better and more extensible way of doing this is to add a custom filter to pass this through. It's a few extra steps, but allows you to easily add further custom logic if you want to override the functionality on a case-by-case basis depending on your product.

First, make a custom filter with a semantically-meaningful name, and put it somewhere in your functions.php file for the theme:

```
add_filter('variable_product_select_text', 'get_text_for_select_based_on_attribute', 10, 1);
```

Then, in the variable.php file, instead of just calling the function directly, pass it through your new filter:

```
$select_text = apply_filters('variable_product_select_text', $name);
```

Setting up custom filters for things like this does take a little bit longer, but you get the advantage of maintainability, since you can stack or turn off functions down the road without needing to further modify your existing code.

**Update for WC 2.4**

Version 2.4 of WooCommerce introduces a different way of getting attributes and their associated selects. Since they still have not provided a filter for this, I would recommend overriding the wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options function using the methods described above. So copy and paste the entire function into your theme's functions.php file starting at the declaration, and add a variable for the select text if it's not a color or size:

```
//Don't include the if(!function_exists(...) part.

wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options($args = array()) {
  // Uses the same function as above, or optionally a custom filter
  $select_text = get_text_for_select_based_on_attribute($args['attribute']);

  wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( $args = array() ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
        'options'          => false,
        'attribute'        => false,
        'product'          => false,
        'selected'         => false,
        'name'             => '',
        'id'               => '',
        'class'            => '',
        'show_option_none' => __( $select_text, 'woocommerce' ),
        'show_option_color' => __( 'Choose a color', 'woocommerce' ),
        'show_option_size' => __( 'Choose a size', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
// Put the rest of the function here
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. However I found that in my version of Woocommerce that particular line is not in variable.php. I did however find it in woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php. I'll add the variable.php code to OP above.

Comment: I believe that the code you indicated in wc-template-functions.php is going to apply to ALL selects output by WooCommerce, not just ones on product pages. Which version of WC are you using? I may be able to track down your specific version's way of doing this.

Comment: Ahh, I see they changed this quite a lot recently. It is still handled in variable.php, except now you are going to be looking for line 33. I'll update the answer to reflect a new approach.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. I have added the filter and defined $select_text lines from under "The Cleaner Way" in functions.php. Then added my original function from my post changing out the Choose an option text out for the $select_text variable. What do I actually change in variable.php if anything? Currently I am getting white screen. Does this look close for the functions.php? http://pastebin.com/yNiLvN1v

Comment: All looks right in the pastebin. Did you also add the get_text_for_select_based_on_attribute() function to your functions.php?

Comment: Also, to clarify, this doesn't edit variable.php directly anymore. Instead it overrides a function called in variable.php.

Comment: Ok I have now added the get_text_for_select_based_on_attribute() function so the end of my functions.php file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/xP9aSjtU also I haven't edited the variables.php, no change from the white screen yet...

Comment: Actually, just looked at your paste again - there were a couple syntax issues. You had a stray forward slash at the top, and also appears that you tried to call the function within itself, with the curly braces not matching up right. Try overwriting what you have with this, and pay special attention to syntax and enclosures: http://pastebin.com/fvkbf7Lp

Comment: Progress! The buttons now are saying "Select a Small | Medium | Large T-shirt" or "Select a White | Gray T-shirt" How would I change these to just say color or size?

Comment: I think I've got it - update the get_text_for_select_based_on_attribute() function to this: http://pastebin.com/JLpbZnSH

Comment: That did it! I marked your answer correct. Would I have to worry about Woocommerce changing the code again and breaking this I guess?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! You should definitely keep an eye on changes to that function in the future. Overriding a function can be prone to update breakage, but the Woo team doesn't usually keep changing the same thing over and over with each release. You probably have a grace period until at least the next major version, but put it on a list to check during future updates. Unfortunately the system won't tell you if there is a function override update the same way that it will tell you a template override.

Answer (score 10):

I have done this using a combination of the other answers here and it worked well for me.

This was done using WooCoommerce 3.3.5 and assume the filter was added relatively recently.

You use the filter for the `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options()` function.

```
// define the woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args callback 
function filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args( $array ) { 

    // Find the name of the attribute for the slug we passed in to the function
    $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($array['attribute']);

    // Create a string for our select
    $select_text = 'Select a ' . $attribute_name;

    $array['show_option_none'] = __( $select_text, 'woocommerce' );
    return $array; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 10, 1 );
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It did! Thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

I found a way with WC 2.5. Add this to functions.php:

```
function my_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html($html, $args){
    $html = str_replace('Choose an option', 'Choose', $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'my_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is actually an easier way to customize it.

If you take a look at the core WC file wc-template-functions.php you can see that the array inside wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options function is actually it's arguments with the following key value pairs:

```
'options'          => false,
'attribute'        => false,
'product'          => false,
'selected'         => false,
'name'             => '',
'id'               => '',
'class'            => '',
'show_option_none' => __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' )
```

Now all you need to do is to change the same key value pair in the function in variable.php template file. So I wanted to show the dropdown label instead of the Choose An Option text so I change the fu

```
wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
    array(
         'options' => $options,
         'attribute' => $attribute_name,
         'product' => $product,
         'selected' => $selected,
         'show_option_none' => wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name )
    )
);
```

Same goes with other pairs. Hoep this helps. By the way, this only works in WC 2.4+ so be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty simple solution for WC >2.4 that avoids rewriting functions and cluttering up your functions.php..

Add the **variable.php** file to your theme (http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/), and change this (from line 27):

```
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <?php
            $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
            wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
            echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : '';
        ?>
    </td>
</tr><?php endforeach;?>
```

to this:

```
<?php 
$variations_arr = array();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : 
    ob_start(); ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
        <td class="value">
            <?php $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
            wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
            echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : ''; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $variations_ob = ob_get_clean();
    $variations_arr[wc_attribute_label($attribute_name)] = $variations_ob;
endforeach;

foreach ($variations_arr as $name => $ob) {
    echo str_ireplace('choose an option', 'Choose '.$name, $ob );
} ?>
```

This will replace 'Choose an option' with 'Choose Size', 'Choose Colour' etc. depending on the name of your attribute.

Comment: I added variable.php to the root directory of my theme (with style.css and functions.php) and changed the code to what you have above and I am getting no change from "choose an option". http://pastebin.com/FBTmmCKq is what my variable.php looks like

Comment: @jfoutch You need to follow the woocommerce template directory structure in your theme's override folder ([http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)), so place it in `YOUR_THEME_ROOT/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`

Comment: @jfoutch You also need to remove the extra  `<?php endforeach;?>` you have on line 46. The stack overflow editor decided to cut that out code block. Basically just replace the original foreach loop with the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to change dropdown text from “Choose an option” in Woocommerce, add following to functions.php file in your theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'my_change_choose_an_option_text_func', 10, 2);

function my_change_choose_an_option_text_func($args){ 
    $args['show_option_none'] = __( 'New Text', 'your_text_domain' ); 
    return $args; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering how to replace “Choose an option” with corresponding attribute/variation name, then here’s how you can do that.
edit variable.php and lookout for the code as the one shown below

Open the variable.php(wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/variable.php) file to your woocommerce and change this (from line 41 to 43): (Remove this 3 line code)

```
$selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( urldecode( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
```

Then add this code

```
wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options
array( 'options' => $options,
'attribute' => $attribute_name,
'product' => $product,
'selected' => $selected,
'show_option_none'=> wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name )
) );
```

It's working all WordPress version
Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me. Seems to be a missing "(" between wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options and array. Works perfectly after adding the missing "(". Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Updated code, made it for anyone still interested

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 
fix_option', 10 ); 
function fix_option( $args ) {
    $attr = get_taxonomy( $args['attribute'] ); 
    $label = $attr->labels->name; 
    $fix = str_replace('Product', '', $label); 
    $fix = strtolower($fix); /
    $args['show_option_none'] = apply_filters( 'the_title', 'Select a '.$fix ); 
}
```